# Trigger a custom event for an "external" value change

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm reading values from a certain process memory. Let's say that I fetch them in the following way:

```
var foo = memoryService.GetFoo();
var bar = memoryService.GetBar();
```

Since it doesn't exist any events for memory changes, I would like to create custom events using polling (if you don't have any other suggestions).

Since I don't know when the values might change, the polling interval has to be set to a suitable value. I don't know how to actually write this, but something like this might do (not sure if it compiles):

```
public class MemoryChange : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Timer _timer;

    public SomethingChanged(double polingInterval)
    {
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.AutoReset = false;
        _timer.Interval = polingInterval;
        _timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Start(); 
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {

    }
}
```

- Do I need to create one class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` for each value (foo and bar in this case)?
- Is there any way to make it run on a non blocking thread (using a `Task` perhaps?)?
- Do I have to use polling to make this work?

Any input is much appreciated!

Comment: Firing the event is the job of **provider** or **sender**, all the subscribers or listeners won't have capability to fire the event, using the `Timer` to poll is another kind of listening, firing the event that way is not really good but in this case we may have to do so.

Comment: @KingKing Yeah, well I coulnd't think of any other way... Considering the circumstances

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to your `MemoryService` from your main view model, then you could define a simple `delegate` to solve your problem.

In your `MemoryService`, define the `delegate` and related property:

```
public delegate void DataUpdate(object someData);

public DataUpdate OnDataUpdate { get; set; }
```

In the parent view model, attach a handler for the `delegate`:

```
MemoryService memoryService = new MemoryService();
memoryService.OnDataUpdate += MemoryService_OnDataUpdate;
```

Back in `MemoryService` when the data is ready:

```
var foo = memoryService.GetFoo();
// Always check for null
if (OnDataUpdate != null) OnDataUpdate(foo);
```

Now in the parent view model:

```
public void MemoryService_OnDataUpdate(object someData)
{
    // Do something with the new data here
}
```

You can find out more about using `delegate` objects from the [Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: Looks good, except for the fact that I need to include this in a timer or similar, right?

Comment: No, you can work out when you request data in your `MemoryService` class in any way you want... this just provides you with a way to get the results back from it. You *could* use a `DispatcherTimer` in that class to poll for data and then use this method to return it to the main view model.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure in what context you will be using your memory service though I will give it a try to answer your quesiton.

1. Yes, you will have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in every class.
2. Yes there is a way, Google knows it.
3. You can use polling or you could listen to PropertyChanged event. That would be the callback approach where you get notified when a changes happened.

Comment: I can't use polling _or_ listen for an event. I have to trigger the event manually inside the polling method. No offense, but I'm looking for a more detailed answer. For example, what are my options regarding running the polling on a non blocking thread? Tasks? Timers? A "Google is your friend"-answer isn't much of an answer, imho.

Comment: I would like to provide you a detailed answer or even a solution just from the code you gave to us and from the description you provided to use I can just refer you to google. You are asking how to do polling. That answer could have been found on google in no time.

Comment: Your missunderstanding me if you think that I'm asking _how_. I'm asking for the most suitable approach for this scenario, since I know that there are some alternatives.

Comment: Ok, still I suggest to do you some kind of callback instead of polling. Listening to INotifyPropertyChanged might to the job.