# Create event handler for an external library's property value change

Tags: c#, .net-4.6.1

I am using an external library that has a property that changes according to certain events. Sometimes the value changes rapidly (only in increments between 1 and 2 though). I want create an event handler to detect if the value is changed and if it does change retrieve the value as part of an equation to move a form to a point on the screen. I am currently using a timer:

```
private var foo;

public Form1()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();

   this.foo = new Foo();
   this.DesktopLocation = new Point(foo.Property1 + 100, 500);

   Timer timer = new Timer();
   timer.Interval = 1;
   timer.Tick += new EventHandler(this.Timer_Tick);
   timer.Start();
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.DesktopLocation = new Point(this.foo.Property1 + 100, 500);
}
```

Which I based off [Trigger a custom event for an "external" value change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121424/trigger-a-custom-event-for-an-external-value-change), but I was hoping for a better solution because the form lags behind the intended point and flickers if `foo.Property1` changes multiple times in a short timespan. I am trying to get the form to follow the point similar to if a user moves the form with the mouse. Before the Timer I used a while loop on a separate Thread with recursion:

```
       private void CheckFoo()
       {
            while (!this.Created)
            {
            }

            if (new Point(this.foo.Property1 + 100, 500) != this.DesktopLocation)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    this.DesktopLocation = new Point(this.foo.Property1 + 100, 500);
                }));
            }

            while (this.DesktopLocation == new Point(this.foo.Property1 + 100, 500) && this.ContinueLoop)
            {
            }

            if (this.ContinueLoop == false)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                this.CheckFoo();
            }
       }
```

The above method works visually as intended for about 30 seconds, but then it crashes with a `StackOverflowException` at different locations in the code, usually at `this.DesktopLocation = new Point(this.foo.Property1 + 100, 500);` but sometimes elsewhere (I have not been able to replicate the other location unfortunately). I read about StackOverflowExceptions here: https://www.dotnetperls.com/stackoverflowexception and it seems it is because I used the recursion loop so I assume I can't use the above method. Is there any way to achieve this without visual issues (or exceptions)?

Comment: This is related to your 3rd party class, inheriting, wrapping, creating proxy on it or anything else

Comment: @AlirezaJ I don't understand please elaborate. Was there a question you were linking or something? `This is` suggests a statement, and the following `related to` suggests you meant to link a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Before the Timer I used a while loop on a separate Thread with recursion:

Why? Why recursion?

It seems to me your method should have been written like this:

```
private void CheckFoo()
{
    // It would be better to just not start the thread that
    // runs this method until the "Created" flag is set, rather
    // that having this busy loop to wait. At the very least, there
    // are better mechanisms for waiting than a loop like this.
    while (!this.Created)
    {
    }

    while (this.ContinueLoop)
    {
        if (new Point(this.foo.Property1 + 100, 500) != this.DesktopLocation)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                this.DesktopLocation = new Point(this.foo.Property1 + 100, 500);
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this sort of polling is not ideal. At the very least, you should create a dedicated thread and set the thread priority to no higher than `BelowNormal` and/or include a call to `Thread.Sleep(1)` inside the `while` loops (that forces the thread to yield to any other ready threads). But if you *really* must monitor the DLL's value at this frequency and the DLL itself really doesn't provide a mechanism other than polling for you to be notified of changes to the value, you may be stuck with code like that.

Do also keep in mind that the call to `Invoke()` is expensive. Even with the above, if the value is changing with a very high frequency, you may still not see updates at the rate you'd hoped for.

Comment: I removed `while (!this.Created) { }` completely, and the application ran fine, but would there be a better way to handle this to prevent `InvalidOperationException` caused by the form not being fully loaded?

Comment: _"but would there be a better way to handle this"_ -- impossible to say for sure without more context. But like I wrote in the code comments above, you could just not start the thread until you know it's safe. E.g. put that code in the event handler for your form's `Shown` event.